# mysql assign variables on multiple rows in select statement

Tags: mysql

i have this sql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT category.title, category.id FROM category 
INNER JOIN request ON category.id = request.category_id;

+---------------+----+
| title         | id |
+---------------+----+
| Clothing      |  4 |
| Dance         | 12 |
| Entertainment | 37 |
+---------------+----+
```

how can i fetch all the result rows of this query as a text in another table like:

```
update message set description = "category : <title>, id: <id>,";

select description from message;

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| description        
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| category : Clothing, id:  4, category : Dance id: 12 category : Entertainment id: 37|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

i'd like to perform this using a stored procedure, but i'm a newbie on this.
thnks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Category: " + category.title + ", id: " + category.id + "," AS Description FROM category INNER JOIN request ON category.id = request.category_id;
```

As a stored procedure (using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html and http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx ):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDescription
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT "Category: " + category.title + ", id: " + category.id + "," AS Description FROM category INNER JOIN request ON category.id = request.category_id;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: HI, sorry i didn't explain it well, actually i want to fetch the result rows of the 1st query as a text in a field "description of a table called "message" . i've updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i use the "select ... into" to store the values of the selected fields into variables that i've declared, so i can use those variables in another query

```
CREATE PRODECURE messagefetch()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE title varchar(50);
    DECLARE id int(7);

    SELECT DISTINCT category.title, category.id 
    FROM category 
    INTO title, id
    INNER JOIN request ON category.id = request.category_id;

    UPDATE message SET description = concat("category :", title, "id: ", id);
END
```